# Angular2 Change Detection: the parent component is not updated

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

My app has the following structure:

`GrandParentComponent` > `ParentComponent` > `*ngFor` `ChildComponent`

The first 2 have an array of objects (`items`). The `ParentComponent` gets it with an `@Input()` attribute from the `GrandParentComponent`.

The `*ngFor` `ChildComponent` part actually looks like this in the template (parent.component.html):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngIf="item.isVisible">
        <!-- some code -->
        <ng-container
            dynamicField
            [item]="item"
            (onChange)="onChangeComponent($event)">
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this DynamicFieldDirective I create the `ChildComponent` with `ComponentFactory` and set its `item` attribute. (Like this: [link](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms#dynamicfield)).

The `ParentComponent` and the `ChildComponent` both have an `@Output()` attribute, that I call in the `ChildComponent`, when I change an input. So this event is "bubbling up" all the way to the `GrandParentComponent`, where I change some of the items `isVisible` attribute:

```
this.items = this.items.map(***something***);
this.items = [...this.items];
//this is the part, where I try to copy my array, so the change detection works...
```

In the `ChildComponent`, the view is updated, but the problem is, that in the `ParentComponent`, the `*ngIf="item.isVisible"` part is not working, it is not updated.

Why is it possible, that the `ChildComponent` is updated, but the `ParentComponent` not?

Thanks.

Comment: A live example may make it easier to find the exact issue

Comment: Not really related to the question. But I would avoid to bubble up events 2 layers. Might consider to use redux instead.